# UTF-8 GET URL encoding issue in Safari

Tags: encoding, utf-8, safari

We have a form (method="GET") that submits to a PHP page, which performs a search.  One of our Vietnamese users is seeing an issue in Safari where the values in the URL (as put there by Safari during the Form Submit) are not the same encoding as what we see in Chrome et. al.

The form element in question looks like this, pretty simple:

```
<select id="province" name="province" class="inputbox" size="1"><option value="">Vui lòng chọn ...</option><option value="Thành phố Cần Thơ" class="">Thành phố Cần Thơ</option></select>
```

After selecting the second option, and clicking submit, the URL in Safari contains:

index.php?province=Thành+phố+Cần+Thơ

From Safari's Developer network tab, I can see it was requested as:
Request URL:

```
index.php?province=Th%C3%A0nh+ph%E1%BB%91+C%E1%BA%A7n+Th%C6%A1&
```

In Chrome, performing the exact same search I see the URL as

```
index.php?province=Tha%CC%80nh+ph%C3%B4%CC%81+C%C3%A2%CC%80n+Th%C6%A1
```

Notice that it's a bit longer.  The HTML presentation is also slightly different.  See Safari on the left, and Chrome on the right:

http://screencast.com/t/hV7PilKRB4gF

The response header for this page is "Content-Type:text/html; charset=utf-8"
The HTML charset is

```
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

When the server get's the content from Safari, the query clause looks like this:

http://screencast.com/t/ZrUrATbVgkS

(I had to use a screenshot here, because copying the query removed the visual differences in the characters)

When the server get's the request from Chrome, it looks like this:

REPLACE(`province`,' ','') = 'ThànhphốCầnThơ'

Chrome returns correct results, Safari returns no results.

Copying and pasting the URL-encoded parameter from Chrome to Safari yields correct results. (There is no visual difference between these requests), possibly meaning the value put in the URL by Safari is incorrect, but when the correct value is there, it requests just fine.

I'm not sure which of the following might be the problem:
1) The values aren't getting into the HTML in the correct encoding/format
2) The values are getting mangled during the FORM GET request by Safari

Any thoughts? Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

You can set the value of this option (ideally all other select options) with rawurlencode("Thành phố Cần Thơ") not the original string